# vector was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve this problem, but I receive this

> error : 'vector' was not declared in this scope.

Here is the `struct` definition that's included in a header file, and the code.

```
struct Vector
{
    unsigned int length;
    int values[MAX_ARRAY_LENGTH];
};


Vector getSquares(double a, double b, double c)
{
vector.length=0;
float minim=min(a, b, c);
float maxim=max(a, b, c);
int i;
for(i=sqrt(minim); i<=maxim; i++)
   {
    if((i*i<=maxim)&&(i*i>=minim))
    vector.values[vector.length]=i;
    vector.length++;
   }
   return vector;
}
```

Comment: What is `vector` in `vector.lenght=0;`?

Comment: The initial length of the vector.

Comment: you also have a typo (lenght) on two of your lines.

Comment: It was a mistake, sorry..

Comment: @BocaBogdan I would highly recommend you *not* use names like `vector` as variable names.

Comment: To elaborate, @PaulMcKenzie probably means because it is similar to the standard `std::vector` container and may be confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing by:

```
vector.length=0
```

you are trying to initialize a vector object that is initially empty;

for that you will need to do:

```
Vector vector;
vector.length=0;
```

Comment: cool, since you are new to stackoverflow I will let you know that you can select useful answers as best answer to indicate problem has been solved

Answer (score 2):

Actually `vector` is really not declared in this scope... The compiler does now what type vector is.

First declare a variable, and then use it.

```
Vector vector;
// your code
```

Answer (score 1):

The structure definition included from header file is just a definition i.e. a new user defined data type. However to use this datatype you need to create/declare an object/variable.
As suggested in previous answers you need to declare a variable of this structure/data type(just like declaring 'int i' for using an integer variable named 'i') before using it - in your case would be 'vector'.
Just declare a variable in the beginning of the function

```
Vector vector;
```